# React + Three.js with OrbitControls on multiple canvases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, three.js, requestanimationframe

I have created react + three sandbox with multiple canvases showing simple tetrahedron model ([demo here)](https://stopyransky.github.io/three-react-sandbox/).

Unfortunately all instances seem to use Three.OrbitControls the same way: no matter on which canvas mouse is pointing - all models capture the event.

Desired outcome is that OrbitControls are only updating canvas which mouse is pointing.

How should I change this, so model in each canvas behave independently? ([source code](https://github.com/stopyransky/three-react-sandbox))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass each canvas as the constructor's second parameter: [See second parameter of constructor](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/controls/OrbitControls).

This defaults to `document`, but if you pass a specific DOM element, it'll bind event listeners to that object instead.

```
var controls1 = OrbitControls(cam1, canvas1);
var controls2 = OrbitControls(cam2, canvas2);
var controls3 = OrbitControls(cam3, canvas3);
var controls4 = OrbitControls(cam4, canvas4);
```